# How to return and use variable from function?

Tags: php

```
$array = array();
$array = $dom->find('a')->each(function ($dom, $array) {
    $array[] = $dom->getText();
    echo $dom->getText(); // WORKING OK!
    return $array;
});

print_r($array); // RETURN EMPTY ARRAY
```

How can I add values to array outside function? In this example I can get these values and show them in function, but if I add them to array and next return array, then outside function I have empty array.

Comment: If you want your function to have access to an outer variable, you have to declare it as global, inside the function :

Comment: sorry, $t that was a mistake. I corrected this.

Comment: @SachithMW The correct way to important variables outside of closures is to use the `use` language construct.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thank you friend for your comment :)

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you try to do. You overwride the variable you try to append an element and then you ask us why the variable is empty? Please think about what you want to do again, try to get it work and then come back with a problem statement.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I would like have variables from function outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$links = array();

$dom->find('a')->each(function ($dom, $array) {
    callBack($dom->getText());
});

function callBack($item){
    global $links;  
    $links[] = $item;
}

print_r($links);
```

Comment: `global` is a terrible idea. [Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables/2496/global-variable-best-practices) is better